# Snowpark datafarme/table alias

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can we keep an alias for dataframe name ?

```
tabledf= session.table("tablename")   --creates table
df= session.sql("select * from tablename")  --creates dataframe 

tabledf.alias('name')   --not working(table object has not attribute alias)
df.alias('name')   --not working(dataframe object has not attribute alias)
```

Comment: Why do you need to define an alias? Snowpark provides a DataFrame API with lazy evaluation. So yo can just use myalias = tabledf and continue "myalias" instead of tabledf in your code? If you want to define a permanent alias for your tables, it's not possible.